# Combine 2 SQL statements different date

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have 2 SQL queries, first one is:

```
SELECT a1.shop_id, a1.val, a1.descr, a2.title
FROM report_ct_shops a1,
     shops a2
WHERE report_id = (SELECT id FROM reports
                   WHERE is_deleted = 0 AND is_published = 1
                     AND report_date BETWEEN ? AND ? )
  AND a1.component_type_id = 3
  AND a1.shop_id = a2.id
```

The second query is actually the same. If you notice "?", that you will understand that i pass data parameters here. What i want, is add to result statement single column - something like a2.val, which will be shown with different `report_date BETWEEN ? AND ?`

Is that possible to combine that and output additional row i want to? Thanks.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name sorry i dont know what that means. i am ios dev, and use sqlite.

Comment: You are using SQL but you don't know what [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database) means?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i may not familiar with acronym but i use SQLite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

```
 SELECT a1.shop_id, a1.val, a1.descr, a2.title, dateFrom, dateTo
   FROM report_ct_shops a1,
        shops a2,
        reports a3,
        (select ? as dateFrom, ? as dateTo) dateRange
  WHERE a1.component_type_id = 3
    AND a1.shop_id = a2.id
    and a1.report_id = a3.report_id
    and a3.is_deleted = 0 AND a3.is_published = 1
    AND a3.report_date BETWEEN dateRange.dateFrom AND dateRange.dateFrom
```

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring variable and use in stored procedure.

```
DECLARE @FromDate AS DATE
DECLARE @ToDate AS DATE

SET @FromDate = '01-Oct-16'
SET @ToDate = GETDATE()

SELECT
    a1.shop_id
    ,a1.val
    ,a1.descr
    ,a2.title
    ,@FromDate
    ,@ToDate
FROM    report_ct_shops a1
        ,shops a2
        ,reports a3
WHERE a1.component_type_id = 3
AND a1.shop_id = a2.id
AND a3.id = a1.report_id
AND a3.is_deleted = 0
AND a3.is_published = 1
AND a3.report_date BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate
```

Comment: Maybe it's also good to underline that your solution doesn't require the OP to restructure his query.

Comment: Sorry, what you mean by OP?

Comment: The "Original Poster" (the one that has asked the question)